Recent horror movie about someone hiding in a basement from a population he believes to have turned evil
I am having trouble identifying a relatively recent horror movie that I watched within the last couple of years.  Here is my best attempt at some details:
A man runs into a childhood friend after having broken up with his girlfriend. They catch up, and the old friend let's the main character stay with him in at his place. We soon come to find out that the main character is seeing that part of the population is evil. The main character spends a lot of time in the basement of his old friend's house preparing to fight against the evil people.
Towards the end of the movie, the main character and his friend are in the basement and the old friend indicates that he believes the main character's "visions" are real. We later come to find out that the main character left his girlfriend because he believed that she was one of the "evil people".

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Sounds like "They Look Like People"

"In New York, the shy Christian likes his boss Mara but is afraid to ask her out on a date. When he stumbles upon his old friend Wyatt who is passing through New York, Christian invites him to stay in his apartment. Christian is not aware of the impending doom Wyatt believes is about to befall humanity, as the people Wyatt cares most about turn into evil creatures. The war between humans and these creatures is close, and Wyatt will have to decide who he can trust to survive."

Preview:



